Failed Building Wheel for Custom Python Packages Despite Wheel Being Installed in Google Colab
I'm trying to install two custom Python packages from a local directory as part of a larger project using pip in an environment where wheel is already installed (wheel 0.43.0). However, I keep encountering a failure in building wheels for these packages, specifically when trying to install them from a requirements file.
The error:
    × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Building wheel for raymarching (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for raymarching
Running setup.py clean for raymarching
Failed to build raymarching
ERROR: Could not build wheels for raymarching, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Requirements File:
The packages specified in the requirements.txt are:
freqencoder @ file:///nfs/code/gqian/img2mesh/freqencoder
gridencoder @ file:///nfs/code/gqian/img2mesh/gridencoder

I have tried downgrading the python version but this has not worked. Also tried installing the packages manually using python setup.py directly in the package directories. Could this be related to the setup of the custom packages themselves, or might there be a problem with my environment's configuration? How can I successfully build and install these packages?
Also : Python version: 3.10.12
and pip version: 23.1.2
